# Transforming expansive "Check all that apply" type questions into random selection of lesser items

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro

I have been facing some difficulties in managing dietary data regarding cereal consumption. The question allows participants to select as many cereal types that they eat (among 300+ choices). I would like to collapse this into just two answers through random selection. The data structure is posing problems. I will outline my problem below…

1.)    Structure of the data now: Respondents are allowed to select all cereals that they “usually” eat. The data looks like (1 is replaced with a code for the cereal)…

```
Cereal 1     Cereal 2     Cereal 3     Cereal 4     Cereal 5  
1             0           1            1            0
```

2.)    I will need to collapse these choices into just two, even when there are more than two cereals selected. What I am thinking is that I would first collapse these choices into as many as each respondent selected. I want the data to be changed to the structure below…

```
Choice 1              Choice 2              Choice 3              Choice 4             Choice 5              
Cereal 1              Cereal 3              Cereal 4                 .                     .
```

3.)    I would then want to randomly select two of these (since we cannot distinguish order of selection) to be displayed like the data below…

```
Choice 1                       Choice 2
Cereal 1 (randomly selected)   Cereal 4 (Randomly selected)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I might accomplish this? I have been staring at my code for some time and can’t quite seem to figure this out. Please let me know if further explanation is needed.

Comment: Can you have less than 2 selected? How should that case be handled? Or if it's all missing? Are these variables all numeric and are they actually 1's or a code? If it's a code please update your example to indicate that. If it's 1/0 you can do some basic math to make this easier.

Comment: And are the 0's actually 0's or missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. Cereal variables are numeric
2. 0 is missing and otherwise the values for a cereal are larger than 0
3. Cereals have a unique code so variable names are not important
4. Everyone has selected at least two cereals.

   ```
   data want;
   set have;

   *set random seed to get the same 'random' results;
    call streaminit(999);

   *declare an array to simplify code;
    array cereal(*) cereal1-cereal300;

   *sort array so that cereals come first and 0s last;
   call sort(of cereal(*));

   *find the first 0;
   *this tells you how many cereals are selected;
   numCereals= whichn(0, of cereal(*)) - 1;

   *get a random number between those two numbers;
   rand1 = rand('integer', 1, numCereals);

   *ensure that your second random number isn't the same as the first random number;
   do until(rand2 ne rand1);
       rand2 = rand('integer', 1, numCereals);
   end;

   *get the values at those random index;
   randomCereal1 = cereal(rand1);
   randomCereal2 = cereal(rand2);

   run;
   ```

There is untested.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the thorough answer. All assumptions were correct aside from assumption number 4. People may end up selecting 1 cereal. Also, the zeros do represent missing and indicate that the respondent did not select that choice from the "check all that apply" question. Would this change the approach outlined above?

Comment: Number 4 being invalid would change it but I'll leave that modification of the algorithm to you.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Reeza, I have been working through this code and found a possible bug. When using call sortn function, this sorts the data in ascending rather than descending order. I was able to use alternative code to create a number of cereals selected. However, using the random number to pull the value from the array poses a problem when not sorted in descending order. Is there a way to sort an array in descending order? I could not seem to find code to accomplish this.

Comment: Try to rename it then and see if that works? `rename cereal1-cereal300 = cer300-cer1;` and then use the new variable names.

Comment: Or sort the array manually which isn't particularly difficult.

Comment: Ok, I am now stuck on the final step. I checked all prior steps and they are working correctly (including the sorting). For some reason, when trying to reference the number from the array, it is returning a zero. I ran a VNAME function to assess whether it was pulling from the correct placement and it is correct. Do you have any idea why it keeps pulling zero or any possible solutions for this?