# Problem: Referencing Array Value, but Returning Zero

Tags: arrays, sas

I have been working on randomly selecting items within an array. Below, I have outlined my process. I have made it to successfully step 6 (with many data checks), but for some reason, when I reference the array, I receive a value of zero. This has been confusing because even when I check the raw sorted data note a certain value, the value retrieved is zero. Additionally, I ran a VNAME to see which variable it was pulling and it corresponded to the correct place within the array. Does anyone know why I am returning a zero value from the array?

```
*STEP 1: Set all non-codes to zero;
ARRAY CEREAL [337] ha_DTQ02_1-ha_DTQ02_337;
DO i=1 to 337;
if CEREAL[i]=88888.00  THEN CEREAL[i]=0;
END;

*STEP 2: Sort so that all zero values come first and food codes come last;
call SORTN(ha_DTQ02_1-ha_DTQ02_337);

*STEP 3: Rename array in reverse order so that zeros come last and codes are first. Sort function above only works in ascending order;
RENAME  ha_DTQ02_1- ha_DTQ02_337=ha_DTQ02_337-ha_DTQ02_1;

*STEP 4: Count number of cereals selected;  
ARRAY CEREALS[337]ha_DTQ02_1-ha_DTQ02_337;
NUMCEREALS=0;
DO i=1 to 337;
IF CEREALS[i] NOT IN (.,0) THEN NUMCEREALS+1;
END;

*STEP 5: get a random number between those two numbers- this works just fine;
IF  NUMCEREALS NE 0 THEN rand1 = rand('integer', 1, numCereals);

*ensure that your second random number isn't the same as the first random number;
if NUMCEREALS ge 2 then do until(rand2 ne rand1);
    rand2 = rand('integer', 1, numCereals);

end;

*STEP 6: Pull value from array using random number.;
Note: This is where I am stuck. I have tried alternative code where I recreated a new array and tried to pull the values from that new array. I have also tried placing the code directly below before closing the do loop. When the code does run, the value for these variables is zero. After many data checks, steps 1-5 work well and achieve their goals. 
dtd020Af = CEREALS (rand1);
dtd020Bf = CEREALS (rand2);

OPTIONS NOFMTERR;
run;
```

Comment: Please show example data that is causing the issue. No need for 377 variables. 3 should be enough.  You do realize that the RENAME statement just changes the names in the dataset that is written.  You should move it from step 3 to after the current step 6 to make that clearer.

Comment: Respondents were allowed to select from a list of 337 different cereals in a "check all that apply" fashion. I want to randomly select 2 of the cereals they had selected. I am aware of the function of the rename variable. The sorting step above only sorts in ascending order leaving the 0 values first and the cereal selection codes last. The goal of the rename was to flip it to descending order. After printing the data to see, it seemed that the goal of my application of RENAME did work. The goal then was to reference the value placed at the random number within their selected cereal list.

Comment: For context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61525204/transforming-expansive-check-all-that-apply-type-questions-into-random-selecti/61528424?noredirect=1#comment108964003_61528424

Answer (score 1):

The `SORTN` call routine needs the `OF` operator in order to utilize a name list.

```
call SORTN(of ha_DTQ02_1-ha_DTQ02_337);
```

A keen eye on the `LOG` window should have shown you the WARNING

```
3214    call SORTN(ha_DTQ02_1-ha_DTQ02_337);
             -----
             134
WARNING 134-185: Argument #1 is an expression, which cannot be updated by the SORTN subroutine
                 call.
```

Comment: Thank you for this note. I was unaware of the "of" importance and actually pasted each item in. That portion of the code was just to shorten it for reading. I have checked and the sorting worked properly. Again, I was able to work properly through the first 5 steps. Any feedback on how to achieve step 6 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rename variables during run-time and reference the value with the new names.

You have declared an ARRAY listing the variables in 1..337 order.  Check, that's good.
You CAN declare a second ARRAY listing the variables in reverse 337..1 order!

You also do not want to use a variable that might be missing, `rand2`, as a index value.

Suggested code:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do id = 1 to 100;
    array X X1-X337;
    do over X;
      if rand('uniform') < 0.75 then X = 88888;
      else
      X = rand('integer',1,10);

      if id=50 then if _I_ ne 10 then X=88888; else X=5;
    end;
    OUTPUT;
  end;
run;

data want;
  set have;

  ARRAY CEREAL X1-X337;
  DO i=1 to DIM(CEREAL);
    if CEREAL[i]=88888.00  THEN CEREAL[i]=0;
  END;

  * sort the variables that comprise the CEREAL array;
  call SORTN(of CEREAL(*));

  * second array to reference variables in reverse order; 
  array CEREAL_REVERSE x337-x1;  

  * count how many non-missing/non-zero values at the end of the sorted variables;
  DO i=1 to DIM(CEREAL);
    IF CEREAL_REVERSE[i] IN (.,0) then leave;
    NUMCEREALS = i;
  END;

  IF NUMCEREALS NE 0 THEN rand1 = rand('integer', 1, numCereals);
  if NUMCEREALS ge 2 then 
    do until(rand2 ne rand1);
      rand2 = rand('integer', 1, numCereals);
    end;

  * assign random selection if warranted;
  if NUMCEREALS > 0 then dtd020Af = CEREAL_REVERSE (rand1);
  if NUMCEREALS > 1 then dtd020Bf = CEREAL_REVERSE (rand2);
run;
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I will start working through this now. Thank you Richard!